# Difference between test and src directory/ code doesent work at test folder

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, junit, compatibility

Every tutorial about JUnit suggest code exact like that. In class within `src` catalog code work, but when I try to write it in my test class, it has a problem with compatibility.

What are the differences between these directories? How to fix that issue ?

> **Error:(20, 29) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<"java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to
>   java.lang.Iterable <"java.lang.Object[]>

```java
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static  Iterable<Object[]> testData(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                {2, BigDecimal.valueOf(123.456), BigDecimal.valueOf(123.45)},
                {0, BigDecimal.valueOf(123.456), BigDecimal.valueOf(123)},
                {1, BigDecimal.valueOf(123.4), BigDecimal.valueOf(123.4)}
        });
    }
```

Here is pom.xml 
Java version here and in Configuration both at JUnit and Application is 11

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: So you are saying if you write this exact same code in your src, the code doesn't throw this error?

Comment: are you using the same version of java for both? Can you post your pom.xml (or whatever you use to build the project)?

Comment: I've put it into sys.out and it worked. Here is output:
 [[Ljava.lang.Object;@30c7da1e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b464ce8, [Ljava.lang.Object;@57829d67]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, that was the problem:
import org.assertj.core.util.Arrays;